# Skip hidden element on :first-child selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, sortablejs

I'm using [Sortable.js](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/) and I'm having the following problem:

I have a list of items that I want to sort, and I need the first element to be wider than all 3 others.

In order to do this, I have the following css:

```
#produto_img {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#produto_img > li {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

#produto_img > li:not(:first-child) {
  flex: 1;
}

#produto_img > li:first-child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

It works fine when I start dragging any item after the first, even if I switch with the first item it works fine.

It creates the following markup:

[image: First-markup]

But when I start dragging from the first, I'll lose the styling because the plugin creates another item on its place and sets it to `display: none`, so the `:first-child` selector won't work anymore, and it loses the styling.

[image: Second-markup]

[This gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8JCI.jpg) shows what's happening.

[image]

My first tought would be to somehow skip the first-element if it is `display: none`, or use something like `:first-child:visible`, but this isn't working, obviously.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: is it possible to hide certain draggables with a class instead of inline-styling? in that case you could use the :not(.hidden) selector

Comment: Actually I'm looking into the source code of the plugin so I can add a class to the hidden created element. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly the `:visible` pseudoclass is still distinct to jQuery. A workaround you can use though would be to handle the hiding by adding/removing a class.

Then it's a matter of overrides

```
li.hidden {
    display: none;
}

li:not(.hidden) {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li:not(.hidden) ~ li {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: I have managed to change the plugin into adding a custom class to the invisible clone it creates. I'll try that out now